# Back-Button does not work properly with progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

so I´m building a progress bar and it actually works fine but theres one thing that does not work and behaves just really strange.
For better understanding I'll show you the progress bar first,
you can ignore the css and html.

```js
                                var teilprozentraw = $('.question1').length;
                                teilprozent = 100 / teilprozentraw;
                                var procentbar = 0;
                                var width = 0;
                                var step = 1;
                                
                                var mainDiv = document.getElementById('status-bar');
                                var childspan = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('span')[1];
                                var childdiv = childspan.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
                                var childspan2 = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('span')[2];
                                var childdiv2 = childspan2.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
                                var childspan3 = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
                                var childdiv3 = childspan3.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
                                
                                document.getElementById('back').onclick = function() {
                                    movebackwards();  
                                };
                                document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {    
                                    moveforward();
                                };
                                function moveforward(){ 
                                    width = procentbar;
                                    procentbar = procentbar + teilprozent;
                                    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                                    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
                                    function frame() {
                                        if (width >= procentbar) {
                                            clearInterval(id);
                                        } else {
                                            if(width < 100){
                                                width++;
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                width = 100;
                                            }
                                            if(width >= 100){
                                                if(step < 3){
                                                    procentbar = 0;
                                                    width = 0;
                                                    step++;       
                                                }
                                                changeheaders();
                                            }  
                                            stepcheckforward();
                                            width = width.toString().split(".", 1);
                                            elem.style.width = width + '%';
                                            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                                        }
                                    }
                                } 
                                function movebackwards(){ 
                                    //check if element finished changing if its not changing anymore, run this if statement
                                    if(width <= 0){
                                        procentbar = 100 - teilprozent;
                                        width = procentbar;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        width = procentbar;
                                        procentbar = procentbar - teilprozent;    
                                    }
                                    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                                    var id = setInterval(frame2, 75);
                                    function frame2() {
                                        if (width <= procentbar) {
                                            clearInterval(id);
                                        } else {
                                            width--;
                                            childdiv2.style.display = "none";
                                            if(width <= 0){
                                                step--;
                                                if(step < 1){
                                                    window.close();
                                                }
                                                changeheaders();
                                            }  
                                            stepcheckbackward();
                                            width = width.toString().split(".", 1);
                                            elem.style.width = width + '%';
                                            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    document.getElementById("next").disabled = false;
                                } 
                                
                                function stepcheckforward(){
                                    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = step;
                                }
                                function stepcheckbackward(){
                                    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = step;
                                }  
                                
                                function changeheaders(){ 
                                    if(step == 1){
                                        childspan.style.color = "#183E4E";
                                        childspan.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                                        
                                        childdiv.style.display = "none";
                                        childspan3.style.color = "#999da0";
                                        childspan3.style.fontWeight = "normal";
                                        childdiv3.style.display = "none";
                                        childspan2.style.color = "#999da0";
                                        childspan2.style.fontWeight = "normal";
                                        childdiv2.style.display = "none";
                                    }
                                    if(step == 2){
                                        childdiv.style.display = "inline";
                                        childspan3.style.color = "#183E4E";
                                        childspan3.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                                        
                                        childdiv3.style.display = "none";
                                        childspan2.style.color = "#999da0";
                                        childspan2.style.fontWeight = "normal";
                                    }   
                                    if(step == 3){
                                        childdiv3.style.display = "inline";
                                        childspan2.style.color = "#183E4E";
                                        childspan2.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                                        if(width == 100){
                                            childdiv2.style.display = "inline";
                                            document.getElementById("next").disabled = true;  
                                        }
                                    }  
                                }
```

```css
#status-bar{
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 40em;
    height: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}
#status-bar span:nth-child(1){
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;  
    color: #999da0;
}
#status-bar span:nth-child(2){
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1em;
    color: #183E4E;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
}
#status-bar span:nth-child(3){
    float: right;
    padding-right: 1em;
    color: #999da0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
}

#myProgress{
    background-color: #EDF0F4;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
#myBar {
    width: 0%;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(24, 62, 78, 0.86);
    text-align: center; /* To center it horizontally (if you want) */
    line-height: 25px; /* To center it vertically */
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="back">Back</button>
                <button id="next">Next</button>
                
<div id="status-bar">
                <span>2. Angebot<div style="display: none;"> &#10004;</div></span><span>1. Prüfung<div style="display: none;"> &#10004;</div></span><span>3. Abschluss<div style="display: none;"> &#10004;</div></span>
                <div id="myProgress">
                    <div id="myBar">0%</div>
                    <div class="question1"></div><div class="question1"></div><div class="question1"></div><div class="question1"></div><div class="question1"></div><div class="question1"></div><div class="question1"></div>
                    
                            <div id="test"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

So the problem is, when you are for example on the second progress bar and the progress is on 0% you can only go back to the first progress bar if you press the back button two times and when you press the button two times it substracts 29% instead of 15%.

**Here is the main code for the back button:**

```
                             function movebackwards(){ 

                                if(width <= 0){
                                    procentbar = 100 - teilprozent;
                                    width = procentbar;
                                }
                                else{
                                    width = procentbar;
                                    procentbar = procentbar - teilprozent;    
                                }
                                var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                                var id = setInterval(frame2, 75);
                                function frame2() {
                                    if (width <= procentbar) {
                                        clearInterval(id);
                                    } else {
                                        width--;
                                        childdiv2.style.display = "none";
                                        if(width <= 0){
                                            step--;
                                            if(step < 1){
                                                window.close();
                                            }
                                            changeheaders();
                                        }  
                                        stepcheckbackward();
                                        width = width.toString().split(".", 1);
                                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                                        elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                                    }
                                }
                                document.getElementById("next").disabled = false;
                            }
```

> Anyone has an idea why it behaves like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your progress bar reaches next step at 0%, your width is not updated and stays at ~85%. Because of this, your condition `if (width <= procentbar) {` in function `frame2()` is true and doesn't update your progress bar.

You can do the following change:

```
if(width <= 0){
    procentbar = 100 - teilprozent;
    width = procentbar;
}
```

To:

```
if (width <= 0) {
    procentbar = 100 - teilprozent;
    width = 100;
}
```

This will solve your problem but it might not be the best solution here. But still works.

Comment: Oh thanks, did not think about that, just tried it, it works, i'll check your answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :) Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer as it really helps me!